# Hilt - what is the Java equivalent to kotlin's "by viewmodels()" to inject viewmodel into activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm following Kotlin tutorial on learning Dagger Hilt for dependency injection. The tutorial uses

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel: TestViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

in the MainActivity to inject the viewmodel.

It requires a dependency: `implementation "androidx.activity.activity-ktx:1.1.0"` to do so.

I'm trying to learn hilt in Java so I'm unsure what the Java equivalent of injecting the viewmodel into my activity is.

This is incorrect and doesn't work

```
@Inject
private TestViewModel testViewModel;
```

and using

`testViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TestViewModel.class);`

doesn't seem like dependency injection.

What is the equivalent of `by viewModels()` in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`testViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TestViewModel.class)` is indeed exactly what `by viewModels()` does for you.

You'll note that both `by viewModels()` and `new ViewModelProvder(this)` don't pass in a custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory` instance - that's because they use the default Factory - the one setup by Hilt to correctly create your ViewModel via DI.